# why my links are not centered ? (in menu bar)

Tags: html, css

When I Click on menu bar `.links` are not centered properly. I don't know why it's happening and where. I even inspect the code but didn't understand. Please explain what's wrong in my code.
I am very confused so I decided not to try more.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav_bar {
    background: gray;
    display: flex;
}
.links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 5% 0 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
.txt {
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: calc(2vw + 1.6rem);
    padding: 0 5% 0 5%;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

/* hamburger */

#toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  label {
    font-size: 32px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
  }

@media (max-width: 1000px)
{
    li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    label {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    .links {
        display: none;
        margin-top: 7vh;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .links a {
        font-size: 23px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: rgb(102, 123, 145);
        line-height: 50px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: white;
    }
    #toggle:checked + .links {
        display: block;
        animation: links 1s forwards;
    }
    @keyframes links {
        from {
            transform: translateX(-100%);
        }
        to {
            transform: translateX(0);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav_bar">
        <div class="txt">LOGO</div>
      <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="toggle" />
      <!-- <div class="txt">LOGO</div> -->
      <div class="links">
        <!-- <div class="txt">LOGO</div> -->
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </div>
    </nav>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Hic odit libero aut blanditiis at iste nihil nesciunt cupiditate enim. Accusamus, facere enim alias libero necessitatibus magni? Delectus nostrum ullam vero ratione quasi quae a aspernatur! Fugiat voluptatum, quis adipisci laboriosam temporibus tempore animi nobis omnis porro ducimus maxime officia sed ipsum sit perspiciatis reiciendis, ad, natus vel repudiandae? Praesentium ut doloremque inventore quo necessitatibus labore dicta magni at rem doloribus possimus aspernatur alias corporis voluptates cumque dolorum, nesciunt delectus magnam blanditiis sed exercitationem cum. Maiores velit quos magni veritatis exercitationem nesciunt repellat libero voluptates dicta eum eius tempora, unde
```

Comment: `<li>` elements may **not** be children of `<div>` elements. Write valid HTML.

Comment: because the logo is taking a space there

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh yes... Thanks man... any idea what should i do next?

Comment: you really want this *abrupt* effect? content jumping down with the animation? it's a bad UX IMO

Comment: @TemaniAfif I know, but i'm trying to understand it for my learning purpose. Thanks anyway for your time mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `txt` div is taking the left space.
You can add `flex-wrap: wrap` on the `.nav_bar` this will get the `links` underneath the logo & icon.

Answer (score 2):

Make the navbar `position:absolute` on small screen so it can take the whole width and you will have the content centred.

You can also replace the animation with a simple transition:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav_bar {
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  position: relative; /* added */
  z-index: 0; /* added */
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 5% 0 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.txt {
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: calc(2vw + 1.6rem);
  padding: 0 5% 0 5%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}


/* hamburger */

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

label {
  font-size: 32px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .links {
    /* added */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: inherit;
    /**/
    margin-top: 40px;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: 1s all;
  }
  .links a {
    font-size: 23px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(102, 123, 145);
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: white;
  }
  #toggle:checked+.links {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav_bar">
  <div class="txt">LOGO</div>
  <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="toggle" />
  <!-- <div class="txt">LOGO</div> -->
  <div class="links">
    <!-- <div class="txt">LOGO</div> -->
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: no no... I tried the absolute position before but it doesn't work for me.
links overlap the other page content. I know it works well, but i don't want to overlap the links.

Comment: @JeetViramgama so share a complete example if you want an accurate answer. Actually there is no content in your question so ..